# How to create Modal screen in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How to create Modal screen in react native something like the video

https://youtube.com/shorts/K-tarwctvPY?feature=share

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React Navigation for your app you can achieve it by following the link bellow.

[React Navigation (Opening Full Screen Modal)](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/modal/)